# MVC3 C# Razorview Printing a PartialView using Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views

I'm trying to have a button print a partial view.

| Mainview | Partial View |

| Users | Profile |

On top of users I have links the user can click on to access his profile or his reports etc...
I created a link  to print their profile with a Media Print CSS to make it look perfect on paper.

The issue I'm having is making it work.

```
function print_url () {
  location: url;
  print();
}
<li data-username="@Model.UserName"><a href="javascript:print_url('URL/Home/ContentView?username=@Model.UserName')">Print Profile</a></li>
```

This has to work for all browsers. Chrome just says no view available, firefox doesn't respond and IE nothing  :(.

If you have any thoughts that would be great.

AJAX

```
getUserData: function (elem) {
  $elem = $(elem).closest("[data-username]");
  var username = $elem.data("username");
  var profile = $elem.data("profile");
  var directReport = $elem.data("direct-report");
  $.ajax({
    url: 'Home/ContentView?username=' + username,
    type: 'GET',
    data: username,
    data: profile,
    data: directReport,
    beforeSend: function () {
      $('#loader').css('display', 'block');
    },
    success: function (result) {
      $("#content").html(result).scrollTop(result);
      //$("#tabs").fadeIn('1500');
      //console.log(result + '\n\n DONE');
    },
    error: function (e, msg) {
      //console.log(e, msg);
    }
  })
```

Comment: Try changin `URL/Home/ContentView?username=@Model.UserName` to `/Home/ContentView?username=@Model.UserName`

Comment: I tried that, nothing :(

Comment: Are you able to *view* that page on the browser before trying to print it? Could you provide more code on your question?

Comment: Yes the software works fine, the view comes up, clicking on another user loads the new profile on the partial view etc...
Providing more code won't really help at this point, it's more a question of resolving the browser issue with printing only a partial view.
the url itself in the "URL/Home/ContentView?username=@Model.UserName"
is working by itself as well.

Comment: Dude, I'm so sorry, I still don't understand your question. (1) Is `home/ContentView` a **view** or a **partialview**? (2) If you request that URL from your browser, does it display correctly?

Comment: Hehe it's ok.
I have a lot of partial views here is the model.
Index.cshtml MAIN View | _UserNodes Partial View | _contentView Partial View.
Goal, link on Index.cshtml to print the partial view _contentView
Currently clicking on users changes the partial view with AJAX providing the url:/Home/ContentView?username=@Model.UserName. Goal is to create a link that prints that URL.

Comment: Ok, and what about `/Home/ContentView`. It's the one at your JS link, that's why I'm asking for this.

Comment: /Home/ContentView is the url created by the partial view _contentView.cshtml

Answer (score 0):

Outcast,

Ok, you enter a `location: url`, then (once i imagine it's gone to the url), you call print(). However, that statement will never be hit as changing location is akin to a return statement i.e. all execution is terminated at that point.

Is there perhaps an alternative scenario that would work for you i.e. doing a jquery ajax call, or is jquery not applicable (i see no tags). We're gorra move fast here!! :-)

Also, as an aside, your URL definition is very very fragile, you should at minimum consider using `@Url.Action()` i.e:

```
<a href="javascript:print_url('@Url.Action("action", "controller, new {username=@Model.UserName}, null)'">
```

... instead as this will guarantee fidelity no matter what your hosting config is like. Tho', my firm advice is to use ajax to call your `partialview`; there's no other way that this is going to work for you based on the info you've supplied.

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense, well right now I'm using AJAX to create the profile view for each user. I've update the post with the AJAX I used.

Comment: How would I make a print function that prints only the partial view with AJAX?